# newsletter css acts weird when sent in mail

Tags: html, css, email, newsletter

I'm supposed to make a newsletter for a client (my very first newsletter). In html it's perfect and when I open it in a webbrowser it's also the way it's supposed to be. I first had the issue of the CSS not showing at all (I had the css in the head of my html code), then I found out about the 'Inliner Tool' on mailchimp. After I did that, my css finally was sent with my mail but not everything is in the right position and I don't really know what to do right now.

My pictures are placed as backgroundimages in divs. Each Div has a size in px, only the background image size is in percents.

Since I'm new here I don't really know how to put my code in my question, so I'm just going to ask you all: Has anyone had the same issue and how did you solve it? I hope I gave enough information

UPDATE:
Thank you for telling me about JSFiddle. I can't put a link in here (sorry), still pretty new to this lol. But you can go to jsfiddle . net and add pht3rnet to look into my code. (in the results, it's exactly how it's supposed to be.)

Comment: Email clients have verly limited HTML/CSS rendering capabilities. A pixel perfect HTML page will often look nothing like it is supposed to in an email. - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Can you post additional information? Which email clients does it render incorrectly on? What's your code look like? You can simply copy and paste your code, then use the `{ }` to indicate it is code. A better option even yet is to put it in JSFiddle and put the link in your post.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to support the majority of the email clients out there you have to understand that there are restrictions on the CSS styles you can use. You can take a look at this table that will show you if a CSS property is supported by a specific email client: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

For example the property `background-image` is not supported by Outlook 2007+ so your image won't show up if opened from Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Joyce, unfortunately their's no perfect way. Every mail client, on every operating system, on every device. They all have a chance to render your content differently.

You just need to discipline yourself to stick with basics and don't get to fancy with newsletters also stick with the top 90% of your email audience.

[Formatting HTML Email For clients](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/forclients/)

You'll find sites that do responsive testing of your emails, you'll find sites that do mobile screenshots of your emails. To me they are all worthless. Responsive is not mobile email (Mobile Email, actually shrinks your content view port to fit the screen). Screenshots are not fluid text, you can't click and test the functionality. That's the most important part right?

Send the newsletter to yourself on your device and look at it. Is it good? View it on your web client. Include a link to a full page HTML Browser edition of the newsletter, so those that can't see it properly have the opportunity to see it, in a browser.

Do [INBOX TESTING](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/services/inboxtester/) - Make sure your clients have the best chance to see your newsletter, you might need more then one version to bypass certain spam filtering engines.